# Play 2.4.1: How to replace all the occurrences of one or more keys in a JSON tree

Tags: json, scala, playframework

Given the following JSON...

```
{
  "id" : "52fe942b790000790079b7d0",
  "email" : "joe@domain.com",
  "username" : "joe",
  "subscriptions" : [
    {
      "accountId" : "72fe942b790000790079b755",
      "name" : "test 1",
      "isDefault" : true
    },
    {
      "accountId" : "72fe942b796850790079b743",
      "name" : "test 2",
      "isDefault" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

.. I need to transform each id to an ObjectID as required by MongoDB (i.e. `id` -> `_id \ $oid` and `accountId` -> `accountId \ $oid`:

```
{
  "_id" : {"$oid" : "52fe942b790000790079b7d0"},
  "email" : "joe@domain.com",
  "username" : "joe",
  "subscriptions" : [
    {
      "accountId" : {"$oid" : "72fe942b790000790079b755"},
      "name" : "test 1",
      "isDefault" : true
    },
    {
      "accountId" : {"$oid" : "72fe942b796850790079b743"},
      "name" : "test 2",
      "isDefault" : false
    }
  ]
}
```

Up to Play 2.3.8 I used `play-json-zipper` and `updateAllKeyNodes` did the trick:

```
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.json.extensions._

json.updateAllKeyNodes {
  case ((_ \ "_id"), value) => "id" -> value \ "$oid"
  case ((_ \ "accountId"), value) => "accountId" -> value \ "$oid"
}
```

Unfortunately with play 2.4.1 I have to remove `play-json-zipper` from my project because it doesn't support the new JSON model.

What is the correct alternative to achieve the same result with the standard Play JSON library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `-` and `+` with `JsObject`.

```
val json = Json.parse("""{"id":"123","a":1}""")

val id = (json \ "id").as[JsString] // find the id
val fixed = json.as[JsObject] - ("id") + ("_id", id) // replace
```

For the more complicated requirements:

```
Json.parse(str) match
  case JsObject(j) =>
    val newId = JsObject(Seq("$old" -> j("id")))
    val newSs = j("subscriptions") match {
      case JsArray(ss) => JsArray(ss.map {
        case JsObject(s) =>
          val i = s("accountId").as[JsString]
          val n = JsObject(Seq("$old" -> i))
          JsObject(s + ("accountId" -> n))
      })
    }
    JsObject(j - "id" + ("_id" -> newId) + ("subscriptions" -> newSs))
}
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work in my case since the JSON trees are quite huge and I also need to transform all the instances of `accountId` in the list. Finally, `id` has to be transformed to `{"_id": {"$oid":"123"}}` and `accountId` to `{"accountId": {"$oid":"123"}}`.